# Why is there: Warning: printf(): Too few arguments on line 59

Tags: php, html, audio, directory, printf

I get an error in my php code when trying to get all the files from their directory, then creating html  links for them and I don't understand why.

Here is the error:
Warning: printf(): Too few arguments in C:\Users\Ryan\Documents\Web Development\xampp\htdocs\muzik\player.php on line 59

Line 59 is:
    `printf("<li><a href='mp3/%s'>%s</a></li>", htmlentities($file->getBasename()));`

Here is the code:

```
`echo '<ul id="playlist">';
foreach( new DirectoryIterator('mp3/') as $file) {
    if( $file->isFile() === TRUE) {
        printf("<li><a href='mp3/%s'>%s</a></li>", htmlentities($file->getBasename()));
    }
}
echo '</ul>';`
```

Comment: Surprisingly enough, the error says there are too few arguments because there are too few arguments ;)

Comment: **How much more clear does a warning need to be for you to figure it out without SO?** Count the arguments, use your fingers. 2 fingers for `%` *(placeholders)* != 1 finger for arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two `%s`, so the `printf` expects 2 arguments and you only put one.

You may want to use this one :

```
$filename = htmlentities($file->getBasename();
printf("<li><a href='mp3/%s'>%s</a></li>", $filename, $filename);
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I missed that.