# c programming in VS2013, Warning: printf(): "Too few arguments when" no arguments are required?

Tags: c, printf, warnings

Hey guys I added this question to a similar post: 
[Why is there: Warning: printf(): Too few arguments on line 59](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22142897/why-is-there-warning-printf-too-few-arguments-on-line-59/32023255#32023255)

and was told to open a new question.

My program still compiles and runs but keep getting this red underline on a simple `printf` statement saying `too few arguments`. But its just outputting a message no arguments are needed.

```
printf("Demonstrating use of operators with an integer variable called 'operation'...\n"); //<<-Warning
printf("operation = %d and -operation = %d\n", operation, -operation);
```

It doesn't matter what I change the text to it always has the warning with red underline. It still compiles and runs but no idea why it keeps warning me.

There was no warnings anywhere until I added a plain `printf` outputting a simple message. If I remove it and type a new one it comes back.

If I put it as the last line of code instead of the 1st one it still does it.

Any idea what might be causing this warning?

Note: I do have a lot of other stuff before this section of code these are the last 2 statements of the last function in the c file. Let me know if u want to see all of it but its a lot. All just basic stuff and truckload of comments (notes to myself just learning c).

Comment: Doesn't seems it will give warning. Please provide more code.

Comment: what if you remove the quotes before/after 'operation' (ie., operation only - without quotes) - still warning?

Comment: That's odd... Could you post a [mcve] along with a screenshot?

Comment: Did you copy-paste the complete statement from you code to over here, so without editing/shortening?

Comment: "Red underline" does not come form the compiler, but from IntelliSense subsystem in Visual Studio editor. IntelliSense does not have a full compiler built into it. It uses a much simpler (and faster) code anlalyzer instead. That analyzer is not foolproof. It is known to report errors where there is none. Something in your code confused it. Mayber the `'` characters in the string. Maybe something from the preceding context. There's nothing unusual is your code being perfectly compilable by the actual compiler.

Comment: Another detail is that IntelliSense does not verify correctness of variadic arguments in `printf`. There's simply no such feature in IntelliSense yet. When it says that you have "too few arguments", it means that it probably believes that `printf` was declared previously with several explicit arguments. How it could happen - no way to say from your code. Could it be that someone redeclared `printf` somehow or maybe overrode it with a macro?

Comment: Hi @Brad, the comments about IntelliSense are correct -- while it has full information for C# code, the same doesn't apply for C, unfortunately. But, on a side note, it would be better not to use `printf()` for output of constant strings, because it unnecessarily scans the string for `%`-sequences to detect whether there are arguments to be replaced at runtime. Just use `puts("[string]")` instead. This will automatically output a newline, if this isn't desired, there is `fputs("[string]", stdout)`.

Comment: Adding to that, as soon as the string you want to output isn't constant any more but user-supplied, a plain `printf(string);` exposes your program to a [format string vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncontrolled_format_string). Another reason to use `printf()` *only* for actual *formatted* output (using a constant format string) and `puts()`/`fputs()` for "normal" output.

Comment: @Felix Palmen and AnT : Ah ok cool makes send guys thanx guys. 
After reading this I re-opened the project to have another look and see if and its stopped warning me about it now. Guess intelisense was a fool.I have never seen puts() or fputs() I'll look it up. (6 weeks of c at uni and they've taught us nothing but how c is different from python witch could have bee summed up in a couple of sentences lol)

Comment: @meaning-matters yes I did shorten the code as there is a truckload of it. If u want to look here is a link. https://docs.google.com/document/d/179yo7gDdAbmHQMi6oQJ0u4CmH_tj-WMHFNl2zgbJhPU/edit?usp=sharing

Totally not necessary for you to do so but if you happen to see something that was causing intelisense to be silly let me know I'd appreciate any knowledge you share.

Comment: Also by any chance if anyone can answer this question also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982780/visual-studio-2013-how-to-make-curser-return-to-point-in-code-after-debug-runs I would gladly pay you a million thank you 's :)

Comment: @ameyCU : see docs link ^ up further ^ for code but think this questions is answered, Felix and AnT are prolly right...

Also you can edit my posts?? And thanX for doing so. :)