# Sporadic "IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call" in VS2013

Tags: c, visual-studio

I'm working on a C program in Visual Studio 2013.  All day long I'm tweaking and rebuilding, tweaking and rebuilding, and every so often I'll get a whole string of errors on all my *printf* statements saying

```
1   IntelliSense: too few arguments in function call
```

All my *printf*'s are of the form:

```
printf("sob x = %d\n", sobelXsum);
```

sobelXsum is an int.

If I close Visual Studio, re-open it in my project the errors go away.   Sometimes they stay gone for hours, sometimes they stay gone for days.  But sooner or later they come back.  Restarting Visual Studio always fixes it.  Is there an actual bug in my code, and if so why does restarting Visual Studio "fix" it? What's causing this and how can I prevent it, or at least reset it without having to restart Visual Studio?

Comment: IntelliSense are not build errors, are they? That sounds weird, since it's an editor feature of Visual Studio, not a feature of the compiler.

Comment: They show up where the build errors appear but I get your point so Ill edit "Build" out of my question

Comment: There are several similar StackOverflow questions, perhaps they can help. For example, comments on this question might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32032565/c-programming-in-vs2013-warning-printf-too-few-arguments-when-no-argument

Comment: @Weather Vane -  that question had 0 answers.  But in the comments/discussion the suggestion was not to use printf's -  that's not an option in this case.  I just want to stop intellisense to stop this nonsense.

Comment: I was just doing a bit of googling... as could you... the comments (as I wrote) suggested that IntelliSense does not live up to its name.